# How to remove duplicates from comboboxes using vba in excel

Tags: vba, vba7

I'm working on a project for my internship.
I have a database that contains repititive entries that i would like to maintain, but i don't want to remove anything from my data base . i've tried multipule codes that i've found online but it was futile.
could you please suggest a code that will be easy to integrate to the existing one?

this is a small portion of my code , it allows the user to insert a refrence (id) to look up whithin my database so i can allow another userform to pop up where it will be allowed to add modifications.
i used dyn_mat as a name manager to keep up with the new data entries in one column. it is is defined by the formula : =OFFSET(Data!$A$6;0;0;Help!$B$2;1)
In the properties of my combobox i gave Rowsource this "dyn_mat" that will go along my growing database and adds it automatically the the combobox

```
Private Sub CommandButtonSearch_Click()


Dim TargetRow As Long

TargetRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Val(ID_Edit), Sheets("Data").Range("dyn_mat"), 0)

Sheets("Help").Range("B4").Value = TargetRow


Unload UF_EDIT

'retreive all the data from the specific row

UF_DATA.TextBoxID = Sheets("Data").Range("StartingData").Offset(TargetRow, 0).Value
UF_DATA.TextBoxName = Sheets("Data").Range("StartingData").Offset(TargetRow, 1).Value
UF_DATA.ComboBoxDep = Sheets("Data").Range("StartingData").Offset(TargetRow, 2).Value
UF_DATA.ComboBoxProject = Sheets("Data").Range("StartingData").Offset(TargetRow, 3).Value
UF_DATA.ComboBoxFamily = Sheets("Data").Range("StartingData").Offset(TargetRow, 4).Value
UF_DATA.TxtTask = Sheets("Data").Range("StartingData").Offset(TargetRow, 5).Value
UF_DATA.TextBoxStart = Sheets("Data").Range("StartingData").Offset(TargetRow, 6).Value
UF_DATA.TextBoxDuration = Sheets("Data").Range("StartingData").Offset(TargetRow, 7).Value
UF_DATA.TxtComp = Sheets("Data").Range("StartingData").Offset(TargetRow, 9).Value

UF_DATA.Show


End Sub
```

Comment: `futile`? Please show us what you have tried and what does not work. You need to ask a more specific question, otherwise it will be impossible to help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: As @OlleSjögren said, there is enough information to help ! Where is the code running ? What is the database ? Is the combobox ActiveX or MS Forms ?

Comment: i added more informations , i hope they will be more helpful

Comment: Instead of using the `Rowsource` to assign the content, you can populate the combobox's  `List` property with an array of unique values from `dyn_mat`.  See similar posts here: https://www.google.com/search?q=vba+combo+unique+only+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: @TimWilliams thank you , i've tried what you have suggested and it worked